# Why are Aero visual style animations missing on my Windows Forms buttons?

Tags: c#, winforms

I wrote a C# Windows Forms program with some buttons on Windows 7. The buttons use the built-in Aero style, including hover and pressed states, but they do not smoothly fade between the different states like buttons do in other programs. Instead, they just immediately transition to the new state. I want them to animate with the default Aero transitions.

## What I've tried

- Ensured the animations were appearing in other programs, like the Run, Open, and Save dialogs provided by the OS.
- Ensured "Animate elements and controls inside windows" was enabled in System Properties > Performance Options.
- Switched my OS visual style between Windows 7 Basic, Windows 7 Aero, and a custom visual style.
- Added an application manifest which specified a `dependentAssembly` on `Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls`.
- Ensured I was calling `Application.EnableVisualStyles()` before showing any forms.
- Ensured `Application.RenderWithVisualStyles` was `true`.
- Read [Rendering Controls with Visual Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/rendering-controls-with-visual-styles) to see if I was missing anything.

Comment: .NET 2.0 supported Win98 and Win2000.  That was a problem, its built-in button was too lame to be usable.  So they decided to make their own, a "pure" .NET control that did not rely on the built-in control.  No animation.  Deriving your own class from the .NET class and tweak it the way you want so you can use it over and over again without any code or having to change properties in the designer is a pretty essential Winforms coding technique.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Matheus Pratta's (for some reason) [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SRT1IAqC7Ng), I learned that I have to individually set the property `ButtonBase.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System` on every one of my button controls that I don't want to have broken animations.

To fix all controls in a form, you can multi-select them in the Visual Studio Forms Designer and use the Properties panel.

Alternately, you can use a loop to fix all controls in a form procedurally.

```cs
InitializeComponent();
foreach (Control control in Controls)
{
    if (control is ButtonBase buttonControl)
    {
        buttonControl.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System;
    }
}
```

---

It seems highly ridiculous that you would have to do this just to unbreak animations. My application is simple and has one form, but if you have many forms, you would want a way to apply this fix application-wide. What if your class inheritance structure does not allow you to add this fix to a superclass, possibly because your form classes are inheriting from a variety of unchangeable (possibly third-party) superclasses? You could extract a helper method, but what about when you create a new form class and forget to call the helper method?

There should be a way to opt in to `FlatStyle.System` as an application-wide setting, and it could even be enabled by default, because every other program in the OS uses these animations on their buttons.

Comment: Yeah, this was one of the most annoying things to me when I was developing with WinForms. The closest I've come to a workaround was subclassing, but as you might imagine that workaround sucks.